# How to make responsive div with picture and description and auto resize picture to div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```css
#content {
    background-color: #ACAE4C;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div  id="content">
        <div class="pic"></div>
        <div class="desc"></div>
    </div>
```

I want to  fit image to class(pic) div, and make all my `id=content` responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css something like this:

```
 img{width:100%;
 height:100%;}
```

Maybe this can help you here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Phoenix404/29a5bfm3/).

Answer (score 0):

For responsive images you can use the following CSS...

```
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will then take up the full width of the parent container.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;}
```

Or if you want it to Automaticly be sized:

```
img {width:auto;height:auto;}
```

Or screen sized

```
img {width:100%;height:100%;}
```

Or

```
img{background-size: cover;}
```

Hope this will help you today!